# Does connection string changes required a new deployment in logic apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

i have a logic app which connects to 2 differnt sql servers to insert some data into tables. If for any reason the server itself or the authentication changes then do we need to deploy the logic app again?

Comment: Why downvoted? When there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.

In the Logic Apps landing page, choose API Connections from the list.

Then select the connection you want to edit.

Then select Edit API connection.

There, you can change the properties usually associated with a connection string.

Comment: thank you. and can we create an api conenction from portal or arm templates? Can you please let me know if we have any arm templates for the same?